# PostgreSQL roles with cyclic membership

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I have a PostgreSQL database that I would like to manage "like a MS SQL Server" database but only for authorized people. There are a few "business tables" to which they should have limited access. I was thinking about making a cyclic role membership to solve it, but am not sure about all effects of such configuration. Here is what I have in mind:

- A group "my_group" which has correct accesses to the few "business tables".
- Each person that needs access is member of "my_group", as well as "my_group" is member of person's role.
- Regarding "business tables", they are owned by another user "my_admin" which is supposed to have full control of that specific database (like a superuser would have, but is not a superuser). It would be member of "my_group".

The idea is that the cyclic membership makes everyone the owner of whatever has been created by anyone else (they thus experience permissions "like in MS SQL Server"). And making "my_admin" member of "my_group" gives it full control of whatever has been created.

The only downside I see with this approach, is that it works as long as the DB is the only one hosted by that server. Otherwise the cyclic membership may bring unwanted permissions on other databases.

- Is it a correct design for managing permissions on that DB?
- Is there any other downside to this approach?

It is also important to note that people using that database have small knowledge of SQL, basically limited to select-update-insert-delete-drop-truncate-create on tables, and will do it via pgAdmin. I thought about telling people to indicate "my_group" in the "role" field of their connection so that they do everything as "my_group", but I'm not sure I want to rely on that to have the desired result (I expect that if they don't do and a problem occur, I will have to connect as superuser to reassign the owner because they don't know/forget/etc. how to do it).

My main concern with permissions here is that deleting a table needs to be owner of that table, and I would want that anyone can delete any table except "business tables". I have access to both "my_admin", a superuser and another user member of "my_group" but would like to reduce usage of "my_admin" and the superuser to the strict minimum required, which is:

- Using superuser only to manage accounts.
- Using "my_admin" only when accessing "business tables" requires permissions not granted to "my_group".